# Call to a member function get() on a non-object in ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2

I am trying to call a function of my module A from another module B. I did this by creating an instance of controller of module A in controller of module B. Though I can call this function, it is unable to access any function with get at its start like getServiceLocator(), getRequestUri(). 
All these errors come when I try to work across modules and not on a single module.
How should I deal with this?

```
class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
public function indexAction()
    {
    $sm=($this->getServiceLocator());
    $newControl=new ChatController($sm);
    $newControl->get_html_code();

    }
}
```

Here, I am passing $sm to the Controller as I can't use the getServiceLocator() of ChatController. Similarly, I can't use getRequestUri().

Comment: Please show relevant code, we can't help you this way

Comment: Are you saying you're directly instantiating a controller instance inside another controller class? By using a new ControllerA inside ControllerB class?

Comment: I added some code @JurianSluiman. Do let me know if you need something more specific.

Comment: @guessimtoolate Yes, Exactly.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to instantiate the ChatController? What is the use case, what problem are you trying to solve. There is probably a better way to do it than this.

Comment: @JurianSluiman I have a chat module that should run when the website opens. So, I want to make a call to my chat modules function from another module. To make that call, I am instantiating the ChatController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *Controller* is an agent where it delegates the information from the request to the model layer. The result of this (a command or query) is via the view returned to the client. If you want to reuse logic, you do that often in the model layer, not in the controllers. TL;DR: create a service layer and reuse the logic from services, not from the controller. Do **not** instantiate a controller yourself.

In your case, you might have a ChatController with some logic

```php
namespace Chat\Controller;

class ChatController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        // do something with the request

        // you probably have some domain logic here

        // return to view here
    }
}
```

For code reusability, it is better to have the domain logic in your domain. The easiest now is to create a service layer:

```php
namespace Chat\Service;

class ChatService
{
    public function doChat()
    {
         // place your domain logic here now
    }
}
```

Now you can make your ChatController **dependent** on the ChatService. You can inject the service in your controller:

```php
use Chat\Service\ChatService;

class ChatController
{
    protected $service;

    public function __construct(ChatService $service)
    {
        $this->service = $service;
    }

}
```

All you need now is to register the chat service in the service manager and register a factory for the controller. In your config:

```php
'service_manager' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Chat\Service\ChatService' => 'Chat\Service\ChatService'
    ),
),
'controllers' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'Chat\Controller\ChatController' => 'Chat\Factory\ChatControllerFactory'
    ),
),
```

And what's left is your controller factory:

```php
namespace Chat\Factory;

use Chat\Controller\ChatController;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class ChatControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $sl)
    {
        $sl = $sl->getServiceLocator();
        $service    = $sl->get('Chat\Service\ChatService');
        $controller = new ChatController($service);

        return $controller;
    }
}
```

**REUSE THE SERVICE**

Now, if you have a FooModule which requires some logic from the ChatModule, create a factory for that Foo controller, inject the chat service and you are done.

Comment: Can I call ChatController function from Service Layer?

Comment: Please read my answer again: no **not** reuse a controller for this. Reuse the code in another layer.

Comment: Thanks for all the guidance. I tried this. But I need to use $service->getServiceLocator()  in ChatService. And I get the same error as before when I try this. Basically, my domain logic needs access to database, so I need to use these functions.

Comment: You are on the right track. It is correct you need to fetch the service locator again. If you want to know why, read a blog post I wrote a while back https://juriansluiman.nl/article/120/using-zend-framework-service-managers-in-your-application

Comment: Thank you Sir! Your answer really helped me clear my concepts.

Comment: I had 1 small query. How do I get baseUrl in Service Layer? As getRequestUri() can only be used in controller. @jurian sluiman

Comment: @user2740957 I would suggest you to open another question for that. Usually you inject the Request object into the service layer, but there is too little room here in the comment section to explain this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24547387/how-to-get-baseurl-in-service-layer-in-zf2
I did that. Got no response till now.

Comment: Well you removed that question, nobody can answer it now anymore.

Comment: Yes. I got the solution. :)